# Unable to start stand alone server for websocket-rails on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, rubygems, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to implement chat like system on my application using [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails). My `Gemfile` looks like :

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'jazz_hands'
end

gem 'thin'


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'unicorn' , group: :production

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

  gem 'capistrano','~> 2.15.5' , group: :development
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'lorempixum', '~> 0.0.3'


gem 'kaminari'

gem "opentok", "~> 2.2"
gem 'slim'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'private_pub'

gem 'devise'
gem 'redis'
gem 'websocket-rails'
```

and

**config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb**

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|

  # Uncomment to override the default log level. The log level can be
  # any of the standard Logger log levels. By default it will mirror the
  # current Rails environment log level.
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Uncomment to change the default log file path.
  # config.log_path = "#{Rails.root}/log/websocket_rails.log"

  # Set to true if you wish to log the internal websocket_rails events
  # such as the keepalive `websocket_rails.ping` event.
  # config.log_internal_events = false

  # Change to true to enable standalone server mode
  # Start the standalone server with rake websocket_rails:start_server
  # * Requires Redis
  config.standalone = true

  # Change to true to enable channel synchronization between
  # multiple server instances.
  # * Requires Redis.
  config.synchronize = false

  # Prevent Thin from daemonizing (default is true)
  # config.daemonize = false

  # Uncomment and edit to point to a different redis instance.
  # Will not be used unless standalone or synchronization mode
  # is enabled.
  # config.redis_options = {:host => 'localhost', :port => '6379'}

  # By default, all subscribers in to a channel will be removed
  # when that channel is made private. If you don't wish active
  # subscribers to be removed from a previously public channel
  # when making it private, set the following to true.
  # config.keep_subscribers_when_private = false

  # Set to true if you wish to broadcast channel subscriber_join and
  # subscriber_part events. All subscribers of a channel will be
  # notified when other clients join and part the channel. If you are
  # using the UserManager, the current_user object will be sent along
  # with the event.
  # config.broadcast_subscriber_events = true

  # Used as the key for the WebsocketRails.users Hash. This method
  # will be called on the `current_user` object in your controller
  # if one exists. If `current_user` does not exist or does not
  # respond to the identifier, the key will default to `connection.id`
  # config.user_identifier = :id

  # Uncomment and change this option to override the class associated
  # with your `current_user` object. This class will be used when
  # synchronization is enabled and you trigger events from background
  # jobs using the WebsocketRails.users UserManager.
  # config.user_class = User

  # Supporting HTTP streaming on Internet Explorer versions 8 & 9
  # requires CORS to be enabled for GET "/websocket" request.
  # List here the origin domains allowed to perform the request.
  # config.allowed_origins = ['http://localhost:3000']
  config.standalone_port = 3245

end
```

On local machine everything works fine by starting the server as described https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Standalone-Server-

```
$ bundle exec rake websocket_rails:start_server
Websocket Rails Standalone Server listening on port 3245

$ ps -ef | grep 3245
sahil     8719  2290  4 11:50 ?        00:00:02 thin server (0.0.0.0:3245) [websocket_rails]                                                                                                                  
sahil     8771  3688  0 11:51 pts/1    00:00:00 grep 3245
```

But same thing on server returns as

```
$ ps -ef | grep 3245
deploy    7249  1348  0 02:23 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 3245
```

Clearly no thin server for websocket_rails running. What may be the issue on production server ?

Comment: bundle exec rake websocket_rails:start_server RAILS_ENV=production worked

Comment: Hi sahil, Im facing a similar issue. My servers including thin, passenger and nginx are working fine but I'm not able to proxy pass the websocket request so it gets forwarded to thin. Here is the link on the issue im facing -> https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/211#issuecomment-78816436 Did you face this issue ? How did u sort this out. Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not having your environment variable set. To solve similar issues, on our production server, all rails apps are running under a single user named "passenger". This user has an environment variable definition in it's profile script reading:

```
export RAILS_ENV="production"
```

We did the same for our capistrano user, so assets precompilation, server tasks etc are ran under the right environment.